# How works DataTable c# with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datatable

I don't understand how works dataTable in c#, Here is my problem:

I have on select, and this select give to me just ONE ID, see

```
 string query = "SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE NAME = 'WILL'";
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

i don´t know how i get this ID and use in other select,

result of Select:

```
 ID = 23 // ID is result of first select
```

new select with the result of other select:

```
 SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = @ID
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
```

How i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query returns one cell, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Looks like you don't need to use `MySqlDataAdapter` in this case.

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query.

```
int id = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //id will be 23
```

Then you can use it as;

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
```

Of course you can use `MySqlDataAdapter` here. You can use *while statement* with [`.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and you can get first column value. But `ExecuteScalar` do these in one line.

> i try with int16 but only works with int32, why?

`ExecuteScalar` method returns this value as `object`. That's why this is an boxing/unboxing issue. From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx);

> Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type object to a value
>   type or from an interface type to a value type that implements the
>   interface. An unboxing operation consists of:
>
> - **Checking the object instance to make sure that it is a boxed value of
>     the given value type**.
> - Copying the value from the instance into the value-type variable.

Also

> For the unboxing of value types to succeed at run time, the item being
>   unboxed must be a reference to an object that was previously created
>   by boxing an instance of that value type. Attempting to unbox null
>   causes a NullReferenceException. **Attempting to unbox a reference to an
>   incompatible value type causes an InvalidCastException**.

In your case your `23` value is boxed. And it is an `int` by default. But you try to unboxed it a variable that is not an `int`. This isn't a valid operation. You can't do that in just one step.

For example this will be a valid operation;

```
Int16 id = (Int16)(Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // valid
```